# Unity // taskbar gone [12.10]

Tags: unity, nvidia, graphics, xbmc

I tried to update my graphics driver to properly use XBMC, and suddenly the taskbar // unity (not quite sure what it's called) the side bar & top bar vanished after a restart.

It is currently showing that my graphics driver is: "Vesa: GT218 Board - 06910002" which is completely unknown to me; it just appeared after the restart.

Note:

- AMD Athlon(tm) II x2 215 Processor x2
- Nvida graphics card

Answer (score 1):

OP added an update to their question along with a link to a solution. Here is the update, and the key information from the link:

> I tried to use the **jockey** or **Additional Drivers** as it was
>   once called, to update my Nvidia driver, rendering my system somewhat
>   useless. I had to manually update my driver with [the following
>   guide](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html):
>
> > Rather than having to do this after your machine ends up with a half-working desktop, you can do this before any damage is caused. Hint, if you've already botched, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to reach the first virtual console. Log in there, then follow the instructions.
> >
> > In the past, running `apt-get install build-essential` was enough. This would get all the relevant stuff, including the kernel sources and kernel headers. Now, you must specify these separately.
> >
> > ```
> > sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-source linux-headers
> > ```
> >
> > If the transitional package `linux-headers` is not available, instead, please try running the command by specifying the exact version of the headers with:
> >
> > ```
> > sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
> > ```
> >
> > And this should work. Next, install the current Nvidia driver:
> >
> > ```
> > sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
> > ```
> >
> > If you skipped the part where you install the sources, headers and the rest, you will get an error here, so, go back and install them correctly...
> >
> > Once the installation completes successfully, check if the Nvidia driver is loaded:
> >
> > ```
> > sudo /sbin/lsmod | grep nvidia
> > ```
> >
> > If it's not, you will need to manually insert into memory. First, make sure all kernel module dependencies are satisfied and resolved:
> >
> > ```
> > sudo depmod -a
> > ```
> >
> > Then, load the driver:
> >
> > ```
> > sudo modprobe nvidia_current
> > ```
> >
> > This should succeed and the `lsmod` command should show it's loaded, but the usage count will probably be 0, because nothing will be using it yet. You will need to restart the graphics environment to actually benefit from the driver:
> >
> > ```
> > sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart
> > ```
> >
> > This will restart the graphics environment, you will see the Nvidia splash, and you will load into a desktop that has the nvidia driver running, and all that. Your problem is now resolved. The skeptics among you can reboot to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you tried to update proprietary driver.
So, you can remove proprietary drivers (return to free nouveau).
Try this terminal commands:

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo reboot
```

Now, you should have all working with free drivers. You can try to install proprietary driver again.

Comment: I tried using the commands you linked, but after the reboot, the unity was still missing, however the "flickering" i failed to mention in my previous post was gone

It now shows that i do not have an active graphic driver tho.

Comment: You have 2 options right now, 1) Move xorg.conf - sudo mv /etc/x11/xorg.conf /etc/x11/xorg.conf.bak && sudo reboot ;; 2) Try to install nvidia proprietary from ubuntu repository - sudo apt-get install nvidia-current && sudo reboot

Comment: I couldnt get the 1) option to work, but however after doing the 2) option the startup went into some sort of "recovery" mode, but the Unity is still missing

Answer (score 0):

I know that AMD drivers need the linux-headers-generic package to work, and I suspect that the issue might be the same with nvidia.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

And then try to install the driver.